# How many missions does the Starcraft 2 campaign have?

Tags: starcraft-2

While playing the (awesome) SC2 campaign i started to wonder how many missions are there for me to play before the campaign ends. Also, will i be able to play all the missions available or does playing one mission (planet) mean that some other mission will not be available?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The campaign lists 26 total missions, though some of these are "A or B" missions. Though you may only complete one of these missions for credits / research / campaign credit, the other, alternate mission is available on the console on the bridge to be replayed any time you like for achievements, etc.

Given the nature of those "pick one" missions, I believe there are 29 total possible missions +- a bonus mission that is only unlocked during special circumstances. (Or there may be 26 missions +- the bonus mission, I'm unsure how the "Campaign progress" bar, x/26, accounts for the branching scenarios.)

Answer (score 6):

25, 1 bonus, and 3 alternates

25 + 1 bonus is the "26" listed at the bottom of the screen.

There are a total of 29.

Answer (score 0):

26, and I think one bonus one. At least I've found just one bonus mission.

Comment: @pixel: This post *does* answer the question.